# Misuse of Equal and Unequal to test equality of colors

Tags: expression-test

Start with:

```
    b = Blue; r = Red;
```

According to the docs, one should use `Equal` (`==`) and `Unequal` (`!=`) *only* for testing equality of such things as numeric objects and string objects; and one *should* use `SameQ` (`===`) and `UnsameQ` (`=!=`) otherwise.

So as expected, the following return *un*evaluated (except that the names of colors get replaced by color blobs):

```
    Red == Blue
    r == b
    Red != Blue
    r != b
```

Now, however, let:

```
    x = b;
```

Now all the below *do* evaluate to give `True` or `False`:

```
    x == Blue
(* True *)
    x == b
(* True *)
    x != Blue
(* False *)
    x != b
(* False *)
```

***Why does Mathematica permit this?***

Comment: Because any expression is `Equal` to itself  and is not `Unequal` to itself.

Comment: @BobHanlon: But why does `Red == Blue` not evaluate completely to `True` or `False`?

Comment: (i) Things that are `SameQ` are also `Equal`. (ii) Things that are not `NotSameQ` are thus `SameQ` are thus `Equal` are thus not `Unequal`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `x=y` assigns a value to `x`. So,
if `x` does **not** have a value,
it evaluates to itself. However try

```
ClearAll[x];
Print[x==x,":",x==0,":",x==Unevaluated[x]]
```

Now do `x=0` and the `Print` statement again to
see the difference. Note that I used `0` as just
an example. **Almost** any Mathematica expression would do, but it is certain for atomic objects like integers and colors.
Verify this for yourself.

Comment: But your example sets `x` to be numeric. Please look again at my query!